# Vaadin: How to check if browser has pdf plug-in?

Tags: java, pdf, vaadin7

Is there a posability in Vaadin 7 or in Java generally, to check if a browser has an embedded pdfreader or not?

I need to know that because it depends on that how i open the pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unfortunately no way to consistently check if the browser supports viewing PDF files or not. I would recommend using something like PDF.JS (https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) or FlexPaper (http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/products.jsp) on your web site to display your documents to make sure your visitors can see your documents

Both those options are available as open source

Answer (score 1):

In a web application, Java (and per se, Vaadin) runs on server side, so you cannot know which technology is installed on client, in this case, the browser. Just fire your file download with the `application/pdf` mime header and let the client do it's work. If you want to fire it as a general file download, use `application/octet-stream` mime header instead.

Here's a more generic q/a on this topic: [How to determine if the user's browser can view PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76179/1065197)