# How to control the load event of a pdf file in adobe acrobat by java script code

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I have a pdf file. I want to display that pdf file only in cases where Adobe Acrobat is installed on the user's machine,otherwise I want to show an error page. How I can accomplish loading of the pdf file through JavaScript only when Adobe Acrobat is present?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine if the user's browser can view PDF files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76179/how-to-determine-if-the-users-browser-can-view-pdf-files)

Answer (score 0):

As the dumb PDF viewer may not understand JavaScript, you will have to do it "the other way round". You will provide the document with the error page, and have code to "activate" it within Acrobat/Reader.

The property to look for when doing such a test would be `app.viewerType`, which could be "Reader", "Exchange", or "Exchange Pro". Another `viewerType` designates another application. You might also evaluate app.platform.